# How to Use operator ""

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I was playing around with some features of C++, and I found that I had to add "ms" to the end of a number when sleeping using std::this_thread::sleep_for() in order to show I wanted to sleep for milliseconds.

```
std::this_thread::sleep_for(100ms); // "100ms" becomes 100 milliseconds
```

I then peeked at the definition for this in the chrono.h source code and found this:

```
inline constexpr chrono::milliseconds operator "" ms(unsigned long long _Val)
{   // return integral milliseconds
    return (chrono::milliseconds(_Val));
}
```

There were also overloads for "s", "us", "ns", and more.

I attempted to make my own version of this but ran into a lot of issues.  I naturally looked online for some documentation and no major website (or seemingly any website for that matter) had anything on it.

Could someone answer with the correct format/syntax for using operator ""?

Comment: You can read the standard, as well as cppreference.com. Othewise, what is the specific code you're trying to get working, and what is the error?

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to state a clear problem you're facing. To get a general explanation on something, look up the documentation. Otherwise post the actual code that is giving you a hard time.

Comment: Also, they're called "user-defined literals", which is perhaps non-obvious. You can find examples [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal)

Comment: User defined literals must begin with an underscore, was this your issue? It is also explained on several major sites, including http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn919277.aspx

Comment: If you search operator on cppreference.com, operator"" is not anywhere on the site or on the operator page.  The problem I was having was that it always wanted a certain data type as the parameter.  I wanted to look up what they were, but there was nothing.

Comment: Oh!  Thanks AndyG!  I did not know the specific name.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen: But that wouldn't be reason for it not to compile. I mean, `std::chrono::literals` don't use the underscore. It's just that the ones without underscores are reserved for future use (and you'll get a warning, but not an error)

Comment: This [article](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2012/08/12/user-defined-literals-part-i/) is pretty good if you have time to read it all. It'll walk you through user defined literals. :)

Comment: Thanks for the article LismUK!